# Display validation errors onSubmit with redux-form, and clear errors until next onSubmit on touch

Tags: redux-form

I am using `redux-form v6.0.1`.

Right now, my use-case involves creating a form where:

1. Errors are only displayed `onSubmit`, when `submitFailed` prop is `true`.
2. When the user goes back to fix the errors, the errors go away, *and don't redisplay until the next time* `onSubmit` *is called.*

My current solution involves setting `touchOnBlur: false`, and having my error message display when `touched && error`. `redux-form` touches every field when `onSubmit` is triggered, so I add logic to every field to set `touched = false` when the user revisits, to hide the error until the next form submission. However, this seems very counter-intuitive (setting `touched` to false when the user touches things). Is there a more natural way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing with v5. Did you ever find a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior is to clear the form-wide submit error when a field is changed. But this can be overridden by the [`persistentSubmitErrors`](http://redux-form.com/6.2.1/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-persistentsubmiterrors-boolean-optional-) config flag introduced in `v6.0.4`.