# Redux-form v5: How to clear/hide submit error after field edited

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

Edit: Focusing the question

### How can I clear the **form-level submit error** for a form wrapped by Redux-Form v. 5.3.3?

I use Redux-Form in several forms with anynchronous Submit behavior. All of them use `props.error` to get the submit error to show the user.

When the user edits the form fields, the error message no longer applies. So I'd like to clear it (or at the very least, not show it to the user) until the next submission.

Editing fields clears the **field-level error property** (e.g. `props.fields.email.error`). How can I also clear the form-level error property?

Alternatively, can you recommend a reliable way to determine that one or more fields have been edited since the submit? I could use that to hide the error message in that scenario.

---

#### The form code looks like this:

```
const MyForm = (props) => {
  const { fields: {name},
    error,
    handleSubmit,
    mySubmitHandler,
    submitting,
    ...otherprops
  } = props;

  return (
  <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit((values)=>{return mySubmitHandler(values, otherprops);}) }>
    <div className="error-message">{error}</div>
    <input {...name}>
  </form>
  );
};
```

#### And the wrapper:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.authReducer.user
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch)
{
  return {
    mySubmitHandler: (values, props) =>{
      const { name } = values;
      const { user } = props;
      return dispatch(doAsyncAction(name, user))
      .catch(err=>{
        return Promise.reject({_error: err.message, name: err.message});
      });
    }
  };
}

function clientValidate(values)
{
  values = trimSpaces(values);
  const { name } = values;
  if (!name)
  {
    return {
      name: 'You must enter a name',
      _error: 'You must enter a name'
    };
  }
}

const fields = ['name'];
let MyFormContainer = reduxForm({
  form: 'myFormName',
  fields,
  validate: clientValidate,
  submitting: false
}, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyForm);


export default MyFormContainer;
```

Thanks in advance!
p.s. This is similar (maybe identical?) to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235203/display-validation-errors-onsubmit-with-redux-form-and-clear-errors-until-next) about redux-form v6.

---

Original question:

### Behavior I'm looking for:

1. User submits the form with "bad" data
2. The form Error message (for the form overall, not for a specific field) is displayed and field text color changes to red using CSS
3. User clicks on the field
4. **Text turns back to black**
5. User makes an edit (types a char or deletes a char)
6. **Error message disappears**

This seems like pretty standard behavior, but I've been unable to make it happen so far. If there's a built-in way to do this (or something similar), I'd love to hear about it.

#### Edit:

Item 4 is handled via the field.active property. Thanks, @Erik!

I would like to know how to clear the error when the user focuses back into the field, or at least when they edit the field.

Answer (score 1):

Making a change to your field value *will* remove the submit error for that field in `v5`, so your #6 should work.

As for styling the text of the input on focus, that could either be done with the pseudo class `:focus`, as you suggest, or by adding a class with the `this.props.fields.myField.focus` flag that `redux-form` provides.

```
if(myField.focus) {
   // set style to black
} else if(myField.touched && myField.error) {
   // set style to red
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Erik! The .focus flag should be just what I need. (Or is it called "active" in 5.3.3? http://redux-form.com/5.3.3/#/api/props)  However, I'm not seeing the submit error cleared when changing a field value. Using 5.3.3. Is it possible that that behavior wasn't present in 5.3.3?

Comment: this.props.fields.myField.active works great! (But just to be clear, the question about clearing the submit error stands. Text color is working, but the wrapped component still displays an error message because its .error prop is still set.)

Comment: Ah! The key bit of info in your answer was: "...for that field." The field-level error is indeed being cleared. I want to clear the error for the entire form (this.props.error). Is there a way to do that? In this case there's only one field, so I don't necessarily need to store both a form-level error and a field-level error, but I have other forms with multiple fields (e.g. login). Is it not expected that people will use the form-level "error" prop?

Comment: In the off case you still have problem, I believe you should be able to re-initialize the form and it will clear errors. haven't tried this exact thing but have been reading the docs a lot lately and seem to remember something like that.